# How do I submit the same name textbox value through AJAX

Tags: php, ajax, form-submit

I have many textboxes which are dynamically added through jQuery. they all have same name like...

```
<input type="text" name="employer" id="employer" />
<input type="text" name="position" id="position" />
<input type="text" name="city" id="city" />

<input type="text" name="employer" id="employer" />
<input type="text" name="position" id="position" />
<input type="text" name="city" id="city" />

so many...
```

I am passing all textbox value through AJAX, but its not working. my AJAX code is below..

**AJAX**

```
$.ajax(
    {
      type: "POST",
      url: $("#cfgRoot").val()+'/accounts/educationInfoPost.php',
      data:
      {
        employer:$("#employer").val().trim(),
        position:$("#position").val().trim(),
        city:$("#city").val().trim()
      }
});
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: You should not use same id's at-least on the same page..

Comment: First of all you can not use same id more than 1 time. id must be unique.

Comment: also, you should be more precise than "it's not working", i.e. what happens?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var empName = $("input[name=employer]").map(function(){
   return $(this).val();
}).get().join(",");
```

And pass it into ajax data.

**Code**

```
var empName = $("input[name=employer]").map(function(){
   return $(this).val();
}).get().join(",");

var position = $("input[name=position]").map(function(){
   return $(this).val();
}).get().join(",");

var city = $("input[name=city]").map(function(){
   return $(this).val();
}).get().join(",");


$.ajax(
{
    type: "POST",
    url: $("#cfgRoot").val()+'/accounts/educationInfoPost.php',
    data:
    {
        employer:empName,
        position:position,
        city:city
    }
});
```

And one more thing **DO NOT ADD SAME ID FOR DOM.**

**ID MUST BE UNIQUE FOR EACH DOM**

Answer (score 1):

What do you think happens when you give 2 inputs the same name and moreover, the same ID?

If you have multiple inputs, which you want as the same name, you should give them similar names at the least.

Something like

```
<input type="text" name="employer1" class="employer" />
<input type="text" name="position1" class="position" />
<input type="text" name="city1" class="city" />
```

Or, you could give them to an array

```
<input type="text" name="employer[]" class="employer" />
<input type="text" name="position[]" class="position" />
<input type="text" name="city[]" class="city" />
```

As far as sending this data through AJAX, you might just want to serialize the whole form. Of course, this is based on the assumption that you want to send ALL the form data in one go.

```
var serializedForm = $('form').serialize();
$.ajax(
{
    data: serializedForm,
    //rest of the code here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your field IDs are not unique, try to make your ID unique and it should work.